# How can I get Python and Adequote running on Windows?

Tags: command-line, windows, python

I broke my BSD box, and I need to survive a few days in unknown Windows territory. I got the Python interpreter running in a terminal by typing `python`. I ran notepad with the prompt as well, but I am totally lost after that.

How can I do this?

```
$ mkdir Test
$ echo "print 'hello'" > test.py
$ python test.py
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone explained in terms of unix tools how I can get just python and a text-editor running? (I'm missing an environment variable; found `C:\Python26\python.exe` but haven't yet gotten the env var correct).

Comment: I am just looking someone to explain me what this thing is. I do not want spend any time to it, I want some quick way to get unix -style tools working. I am not sure which is the best option. Perhaps some virtualized unix or something like that? I am happy if I get python working because I can handle most stuff with it but I am interested to know how you other folks handle things like this when you MUST just use the shxt?

Comment: Nevermind. Add any specific question to your question and I'll update my answer. My solution is to add GnuWin32, vim, ie. decent tools to the environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example `mkdir Test; echo "print 'hello'" > test.py; python test.py` is actually valid in Windows Command Prompt, provided that you have set the Environment Variable as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17093/broke-my-bsd-dev-box-and-got-windows-box-how-can-i-get-python-and-adequote-text/17094#17094).  You can also set Variables temporarily or list all your current Variables using the `set` keyword, enter `set /?` in command prompt for more.   (to set it permanantly use the `setx` utility, download from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=18546)).

To list where something is in the path (`which` work-alike, if you don't use cygwin), use the script I posted [here](http://pastebin.com/7wuQ1W8E).

For a start, do yourself a favor and download [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) plus [Cygwin Ports](http://sourceware.org/cygwinports/) and add the cygwin /bin directory to the Path.

Comment: It apparently creates some sort of virtual directory structure. How can I find the C:\Python26\ there? Where does it place the original structure?

Comment: @hhh: are you speaking about cygwin?,  let's say you installed it as C:\cygwin, the cygwin directory is like /, there is a /cygdrive folder under which the whole file-system is mounted (you got the loop?...).  so to access C:\Python26\ you do `cd /cygdrive/c/Python26` in cygwin's shell.  also take a look at the `chere` package.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already installed the interpreter try on the prompt:

```
echo %PATH%
```

Is python on the PATH? If not, right click on `My Computer`, then `Properties`, then `Advanced`, then `Environmental Variables` and add it.

Python should comes with IDLE. Can't you find it on the start menu? IDLE has a text editor. You could also download `vim` or wherever suits your taste.

Also I'd suggest you to download [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) and add it to the path. This way you get a more familiar environment and less crude tools than wherever comes with Windows.

Comment: how can I find the location of the python installed to this box? Is there something like locate/whereis?

Comment: @hhh Nothing similar to locate as far as I know. Python usually installs itself on the `C:\` root as `C:\Python{version}` (like `C:\Python26`). Just take a look C:\ using the `My Computer` icon. Or you can right click on Python icon in the start menu, look at `Properties` and see where the shortcut points to.

Comment: I found python in C:\Python26\python.exe but I cannot find the executable (the file to add to the env var).

Comment: @hhh Add just C:\Python26 to the %PATH%. You must close the prompt and open another one before changes to %PATH% take effect.

Comment: [here](http://pastebin.com/7wuQ1W8E) I pasted a `which` work-alike in Windows CMD.  HTH.